# OOP python - removing class instance from a list

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list where I save the objects created by a specific class.

I would like to know, cause I can't manage to solve this issue, how do I delete an instance of the class from the list?

This should happen based on knowing one attribute of the object.

Comment: The next time you should add an example of the code that you can't get to work, also accept the answer that most helped you in solving the problem and up-vote the useful ones.

Comment: You're welcome, you may also want to follow some of the advice in this [Style guide for questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18616/177799). A better question leads to better answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Iterate through the list, find the object and its position, then delete it:

```
for i, o in enumerate(obj_list):
    if o.attr == known_value:
        del obj_list[i]
        break
```

Comment: This works great if it's only one element you need to remove, otherwise @unutbu's answer works.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
thelist = [item for item in thelist if item.attribute != somevalue]
```

This will remove **all** items with `item.attribute == somevalue`.

If you wish to remove just **one** such item, then use [WolframH's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140906/190597).

Comment: A filter would work like the list comprehension, but typically calling `filter` is slower than a list comprehension.

Comment: Hey man can you be my mentor on Python? I won't disturb you too much I promise.

Answer (score 2):

You could have stored them in a dict and removed them by name

```
di = {"test" : my_instance()}
del di['test']
```