# Having difficulties to delete class instances from a list in python

Tags: python, list, class, instances, del

I have seen a similar question [OOP python - removing class instance from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140857/oop-python-removing-class-instance-from-a-list), but the solution is not working for me.

I made a full class test. And the result is not passing the test.

I'm using python 3.4.4

```
import random
```

A simple class

```
class J():
    def __init__(self):
        self.jota = 0

    def up_j(self):
        self.jota = random.choice([2, 0])

    def get_j(self):
        return self.jota

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.jota)
```

A list in which I can append instances of the class

```
a = []
```

Appending class instances

```
for i in range(20):
    a.append(J())
```

Changing it up a bit

```
for e in a:
    e.up_j()
```

### Here is the FUNCTION I want to get right

```
def x(a):
    for i, o in enumerate(a):
        if o.get_j() == 0:
           del a[i]
    return a
```

Applying the function

```
a = x(a)
```

Testing! Notice that all numbers in the result should be zero.
But that is not the case

```
for each in a:
    print(each)
```

Results!

```
2
2
0
0
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are removing values from the list while iterating. This almost never works. Instead of deleting values out of the list while iterating, create a new list and append the values you care about (i.e. you wouldn't delete):

```
def x(a):
    ret = []
    for i, o in enumerate(a):
        if o.get_j() != 0:
           ret.append(o)
    return ret
```

Comment: alternatively, `ret = [o for o in a if o.get_j() != 0]` or `ret = filter(lambda o: o.get_j() != 0, a)`

Comment: Thanks @tkausl. But my lists are enormous. Is it possible to work with the same list? Would a[:] work?

Comment: If your lists are enormous, use the `filter` approach